# JSF 2 : selection grouping with SelectItemGroup + POJO

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have tried working with the grouped selections with something like this :

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectionLabBean.oneSelectMenuGroup}"
    id="SelectOneMenuGroup" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{selectionLabBean.heroGroupList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<p:message for="SelectOneMenuGroup" />
```

where the heroGroupList is something like this :

```
SelectItem[] heroArr = new SelectItem[] {
    new SelectItem("Paladin"),
    ...
};
heroListWithGrouping.add(
    new SelectItemGroup("Human", 
        "A collection of human race Heroes", 
        false,
        heroArr
    )
);
.....
```

And i'm left wondering if i can do this kind of grouping with POJOs instead of SelectItem objects ?

If i couldnt achieve this, i think i have to somehow convert my domain objects or my query results into arrays of SelectItem to make it work.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's indeed not possible when you want to use `SelectItemGroup`. You need to convert from collection of POJO's to `List<SelectItem>` in a double for-loop during bean's (post)construction.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    List<HeroRace> heroRaces = getItSomehowFromDatabase();
    this.heroGroupList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    for (HeroRace heroRace : heroRaces) {
        SelectItemGroup group = new SelectItemGroup(heroRace.getName()); // Human, etc
        List<SelectItem> heroes = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        for (Hero hero : heroRace.getHeroes()) {
            heroes.add(new SelectItem(hero.getName()); // Paladin, etc
        }
        group.setSelectItems(heroes.toArray(new SelectItem[heroes.size()]));
        this.heroGroupList.add(group);
    }
}
```

You could also use `Hero` as item value

```
heroes.add(new SelectItem(hero, hero.getName()); // Paladin, etc
```

so that you can bind `#{selectionLabBean.oneSelectMenuGroup}` to a `Hero` type instead of `String`. But then you need to supply a `Converter`. That part is already answered by Amorfis.

Comment: So, the conclusion is : to use grouped selection, we have to convert POJO to List<SelectItem>.  But we still can use POJO as the itemValue with converter. Coooool ! Thank you BalusC.

Comment: I tried binding it to Hero type,but it failed with error : SelectOneMenuGroup: Validation Error: Value is not valid, which is strange, since i dont use any validation at all.<h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectionLabBean.oneSelectMenuGroupPojo}" ...  converter="heroConverter"> <f:selectItems value="#{selectionLabBean.heroPOJOGroupList}" /> .. And at the managedbean, the binding is : private HeroBean oneSelectMenuGroupPojo; I debugged it and found out the proggie doesnt set the binding value. I've tried var="hero" itemValue="#{hero}" itemLabel="#{hero.name}", but also failed.

Comment: This can happen whenever the selected item doesn't match any of the items in the list by the `equals()` method. Likely the `equals()` method is not implemented or poorly implemented.

Comment: It works, yay. I just found out that this is a special behaviour in selection. Before setting the submitted value, it will check the submitted converted value to the list. Ahh i finally understand what amorfis really meant. Thank you all ! Happy new year !!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can return List or array of POJOs instead of SelectItems. You'll need converter for this to work, but it's not a big deal. So, converter first:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Hero.class)
public class HeroConverter implements Converter {

  @Override
  public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
      return new Hero(value);
  }

  @Override
  public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
      return ((Hero)value).getName();
  }
}
```

Now if you return list of `Hero`es to `<f:selectItems>`, you have options in HTML where label is `Hero.toString()`, and value is returned from `HeroConverter.getAsString()`.

One more thing. If you submit some value for this selection, JSF converts it to object and checks (by equals() method) if this object was in list of objects for selection. So in case above, you'll need to override `equals()` in `Hero` to check if names are equal. Another solution is not to create new instance in `getAsObject`, but to keep somewhere list of available `Hero`es and return this list to `<f:selectionItems>` and return object from this list in `getAsObject()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This equals thing and not creating a new instance is something new to me in understanding JSF converters. Have a nice day !