# JSF2- Option grouping using tag <h:selectOneListbox >

Tags: jsf-2.2

This question is related to Post

[JSF 2 : selection grouping with SelectItemGroup + POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553093/jsf-2-selection-grouping-with-selectitemgroup-pojo)

Basically this works fine with tag - h:selectOneMenu but when tried with tag -h:selectOneListbox it outputs only SelectItemGroup elements and ignores SelectItem elements.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the answer- basically render class for component SelectOneMenu supports grouping which is not the case with render for SelectOneListbox component.

To enable grouping with SelectOneListbox we have to write customised render inline with render class for component SelectOneMenu that considers SelectItemGroup